# New roommate from India does something to make bathroom smell really bad

Tags: united-states, india, personal-hygiene

Where I live I share the bathroom with one other person. The person who I share it with recently changed and someone from India moved in. He said he's new to the country and just arrived recently.

I know this is a strange question, but the bathroom smells really bad after he started using it. It smells strongly of urine. Even when there's none in the toilet or on the floor. I noticed he sometimes gets it on the seat and doesn't clean it up.

I don't even know how to bring up this topic. My goal is to get the bathroom to smell better. Also I'm concerned about hygiene.

Comment: a bit related [How to ask a friend/roommate to do/to stop doing something? And how not to feel bad asking?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/how-to-ask-a-friend-roommate-to-do-to-stop-doing-something-and-how-not-to-feel?rq=1)

Comment: Does your roomate know how to use toilet paper and that it is disposed in the toilet? We recently had a question here where it was pointed out that in india, bidets are very popular and that a person disposed of toilet paper in the trash bin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Insights of the problem**

I am Indian and I can confirm such behaviour.

The problem is, in most parts of India, we use bidet as opposed to the tissue papers. Also, even today, many homes have a hole-style toilets and not really the toilet with a seat. The person is habituated to squat instead of sitting on the toilet seat.

If the guy is from urban area, don't be shocked to know if he doesn't know that he is supposed to lift the seat before peeing.

It is a lack of know-how. That's all.

**Solution**

Be upfront.

We like being told things on our face. If we do not know something, let us know. Directly.

Hanging 'rules' will not really help.

Don't overthink. Just go ahead and speak up. Also, if he shows a face like "I dont know what you are talking about...", dont try to convince further because that is exactly how you we would react.

Comment: This doesn't really say what to do, just gives background info.

Comment: First sentence below "Solution"

Comment: @Gertsen When a sentence looks vague, read the rest of it.

Comment: @Gertsen, I am also an Indian I can confirm and I agree with it